# Class Naming Conundrum

Tags: c#, design, naming-standards

I am working on a personal project that works with databases, and in this project I have a set of classes that are *similar*, so they inherit from a common base class. The problem I am faced with is that I have this nagging feeling that the names of the classes that derive from the base class do not really reflect what they actually are.

Caveat: Please ignore the fact that this looks like a reinvention of the wheel. That's the point of the project.

The common base class is called Entity. Its purpose is to serve as the base for:

1. Classes that describe the data returned by a SQL query or stored procedure, or
2. Classes that describe a SQL query or stored procedure and their parameters.

Both of these classes are created by consumers of the assembly to describe the stored procedures and queries in their database, and the data they will retrieve from it.

For example, these are designed to work against the Northwind database:

```
public class Employee : DataEntity
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

[Sql(@"SELECT [EmployeeId], [LastName], [FirstName] 
       FROM [Employees] 
       ORDER BY [LastName], [FirstName]")
public class SelectEmployee : SqlEntity
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

As it stands, I am currently calling the first of these Data Entities, and the second SQL Entities. However, I am not entirely sure that these are fitting terms. For instance, are they actually *models*? Is there a better term that I am not considering?

The assembly only considers public properties that have both a getter and a setter. The developer can add anything else to it if he or she needs to. So a Data Entity can be extended to include additional functionality.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

It's worth noting that you can also model stored procedures with this stuff (again, using a Northwind database stored procedure):

```
[Sql()]
public class CustOrderHist
{
    [Parameter("@CustomerId", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NChar, MaxLength = 5)]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

The assembly automatically binds classes to stored procedures, and properties to parameters.

Comment: The second thing looks like a "query" to me.

Comment: Yes, that should be called Query I think.

Comment: I should probably have noted that SqlEntity also supports stored procedures. So Query isn't exactly a fitting name. :-/

Comment: @MikeHofer don't confuse what a class does with what features it has. If you tightly couple features and class name, then you will have to rename it every time you add a new feature.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I am completely open to a better name for all of these classes! I am a huge fan of clarity. Suggest something! (And do it in the answers section, so you get credit!)

Comment: @MikeHofer to me a store procedure is still called via a query, and if developers need to know it supports store procedures then those details go into the class comments. Is this class `abstract` only?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: Yes. All three classes (Entity, SqlEntity and DataEntity) are abstract. Consumers provide an object to the "data framework" that derives from either SqlEntity or DataEntity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When naming classes it's often tempting to include words that describe usage in programming terms. These words might include `abstract`, `entity`, and/or `base`. So you end up creating classes like `AbstractOffice` or `BaseOffice`. The name of the class implies two meanings what it does `Office` and how it's used `Abstract`. I don't recommend doing this. It adds extra details in the name that it doesn't need.

**KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid)**

I recently refactored a project I did a year ago to use simple names, and it became much easier to read the code. Give it a try and see if it helps. You can always rename the classes later.

```
public class Employee : Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

[Sql(@"SELECT [EmployeeId], [LastName], [FirstName] 
   FROM [Employees] 
   ORDER BY [LastName], [FirstName]")
public class Employees : Query
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When you remove programming specific terms (i.e. I removed `Select`, `Entity` and renamed `Sql` to `Query`). The classes become more readable. Now their names infer only specific information (i.e. this is about an employee). The implementation that it uses SQL or represents an entity pattern is irrelevant. That information should go into the class comments not it's name.

In the future, you will have a bug. Which description is easier to understand, and a result easier to find in the source code.

> **Employee** John Smith is not an active member of **Employees**.

or

> **EmployeeEntry** John is not an active member of **SelectEmployee**

That's just an example, but later when you're using those classes the code becomes difficult to read. A sea of terms that aren't relevant to what the code is doing.

Comment: +1: whatever you do, don't look at the Spring code for naming inspiration ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer Java is the worse for class names. It's like find Waldo. Can you find `Button` in `AbstractButtonInterfaceSerializableImpl`.

Comment: Not all of Java is that bad, however. The JDK is bad, but not as bad as Spring. And Guava, for example, is pretty neat in their naming.

Comment: Good post. This is something where BDD really comes into its own as you're forced to evaluate naming conventions in the light of real business logic.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: Currently, both SqlEntity and DataEntity derive from Entity. Your suggestion is to rename SqlEntity to Query, and drop the -Entity suffix from both of them? I like it. Only problem is that SqlEntity (as it currently stands) can handle stored procedures as well.

Comment: @MikeHofer: why does `SqlEntity` extend `Entity`? Is it an "entity"? What does "Entity" signify in that context? "something-that-has-to-do-with-the-database"?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: That was exactly the issue I had with the name, and why I created this post. :) It didn't seem correct. The reason it derives from Entity, along with DataEntity, is because the underlying engine needs to know about these two types, and they share a number of common properties and methods (which are used for runtime reflection). I didn't want to have to duplicate the code.

Comment: Hmmm...pretty interesting response. I wouldn't often have dared to name two classes the same thing, but I guess that's what namespaces are for.

Comment: @MikeHofer - Sounds like a good use for an `IDatabaseObject` interface to indicate that it connects to a database.  Or a shared `DatabaseObject` class which both `Data` and `Query` can inherit from.  Depends on how much actual functionality would need to be shared.